# Python save an open powerpoint presentation

Tags: python, powerpoint

I am developing an application that creates powerpoint presentations and am wondering if there is a way to save a .pptx file that is opened by the user in system (not in python) with code?

Comment: Please provide some code , otherwise it is difficult for us to help you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.